# Compute $P(A=0, B=0)$ given random variables $X$ and $Y$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, bernoulli-distribution

Given random variables $X$ and $Y$ with a $Ber(\frac{1}{2})$ Distribution, define random variable $A = X + Y$ and $B = |X - Y|$

Compute

1. $P(A = 0, B = 0)$
2. $P(A = 1)$

I'm not quite sure how to approach this, I've tried to individually add up the probabilities as in $P(X = 0) = 0.5$ and so forth but that doesn't seem to work out.

Would appreciate any help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent ?

Comment: @Hamdiken I'm not sure, I didn't write that part down.. apologies.

Comment: @JakeDrone I cannot answer your question when you delete your post.

Comment: Hey @callculus42 Really sorry about that. It's just that I saw that its not about solving an inequality, $3W-2$, for me to figure out the new bounds of the uniform distribution I just had to plug in the old bound in this formula. Old bound was $U(5,6)$ so (3(5)-2 would be the lower bound, etc.

Comment: @JakeDrone O.K. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

I'll be treating the case where $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Since $X\in \{0,1\}$ and $Y\in \{0,1\}$, then
$$X+Y=0 \text{ and }|X-Y|=0 \implies X=Y=0. $$
Then
$$\mathbb P(A=0,B=0)=\mathbb P(X=0,Y=0),$$ and it stops here.

If however $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then
$$\mathbb P(X=0,Y=0)=\mathbb P(X=0)\times\mathbb P(Y=0)=\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{4}.$$
Same applies on the second one (if we assume the independence)
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(A=1)&=\mathbb P(X+Y=1)\\
&=\mathbb P\left((X=0,Y=1)\vee(X=1,Y=0)\right)\\
&=\mathbb P(X=1,Y=0)+\mathbb P(X=0,Y=1)-\underbrace{\mathbb P((X=1,Y=0)\cap(X=0,Y=1))}_{\emptyset}\\
&=\mathbb P(X=1,Y=0)+\mathbb P(X=0,Y=1) \leftarrow\text{It stops here }\\
&=\left(\mathbb P(X=1)\times\mathbb P(Y=0)\right)+\left(\mathbb P(X=0)\times\mathbb P(Y=1)\right)\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{2}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}'